# Writing an input validation loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, validation

I'm trying to code an input validation loop for the difficuilty selection of a game...

```
while True:
diffChoice = input("Select a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()

if diffChoice in ('e', 'm', 'h', 1, 2, 3):
    break
else:
    diffChoice = input("Incorrect input...\nSelect a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()
```

The problem is that when I enter an incorrect input it correctly prints the error however when I then enter the correct input the loop goes back to the start and asks for input again.

Any advice welcomed or if you know a better way to write this validation loop, please let me know!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Second "input" should be a "print" with less text. The loop then goes back to the "input" anyway.

Comment: By "correct input", do you mean `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`? Note that those strings are distinct from the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`

Comment: That makes sense Michael - it worked! 

"1", "2", "3" was just another option for entering game difficuilty. However you are right! I changed those integers to strings and that helped as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    diffChoice = input("Select a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()

    if diffChoice in ('e', 'm', 'h', 1, 2, 3):
        break
    else:
        diffChoice = input("Incorrect input...\nSelect a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()
```

The `while True` causes loop to run forever and since you have `break` statement inside the if condition only, it's likely that always the else part is getting executed..
notice your if condition `diffChoice in ('e', 'm', 'h', 1, 2, 3)`, 1,2,3 are integers however they are always going to be read as character/string because you are not performing any type conversion..
You should consider changing the if conditional to use integer values as characters/strings..

```
diffChoice in ('e', 'm', 'h', '1', '2', '3')
```

Another thing I noticed is, you are asking for input in the else part also, so when you enter wrong answer once, you go to else part and it asks for input and since there is no condition inside the else part any further, the loop again continues, and it starts asking for the input again..
So for wrong answer, you are asking for the input twice..
After fixing these issues, your code should be something similar to:

```
while True:
    diffChoice = input("Select a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()

    if diffChoice in ('e', 'm', 'h', '1', '2', '3'):
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input...\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This seems to have solved my issues :)

Answer (score -1):

```
first_time_asking=True
while True:
    if (first_time_asking):
        diffChoice = input("Select a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()
    else:
        diffChoice = input("Incorrect input...\nSelect a difficuilty...\n[e]asy, [m]edium, [h]ard: ").lower()

    if diffChoice in ('e', 'm', 'h', 1, 2, 3):
        break
    else:
        first_time_asking=False
```

Try this !! .

In your code if you enter input correctly it goes to if condition and while loop breaks. But if you enter incorrect one it goes to else condition and it asks for input again. After you give input for input in else, while loop start again and you will be asked input for first line in while loop.

However in the code given in answer it only asking input at the begin of the while loop. By using variable "first_time_asking" you can know whether previous input was right or wrong. Depend on that we switch the statement of the input we asking for.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.